# Form data failing to submit only on Mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, mobile

I have a contact form that is connected to my mongoDB database, I use Axios post method to submit the form data to my database, it works fine on my PC locally and i also deployed my project to Vercel and Netlify which also works and submits on my pc, but it fails to submit on mobile the both on Vercel and Netlify

```
    //state to store form data
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        message: "",
    });

    // updating the state 
    const HandleChange = (e:any) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

   // submitting the form data
    const HanleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setLoading(true)

        axios.post("http://example/api/emails", {
            name: formData.name,
            lastName: formData.lastName,
            email: formData.email,
            message: formData.message

        })
        .then((response) =>{
            console.log("form data sent", response.status);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setStatus(true);
                setLoading(false);
                setHeading("submitted");
                setModalText("form submitted, thank you");
            }, 3000);
        })
        .catch((error) =>{
            console.log(error);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setStatus(true);
                setLoading(false);
                setHeading("Error");
                setModalText("form failed to submit, consider using my email: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            }, 3000);
        });

    }
```

this is how it works:

1. It saves the form data in a state
2. The state is updated when the user types in each field
3. Then the data is submitted via the post method to my database
4. If the data was sent it return it returns a successful response and if it fails it returns an error
   It always seems to return an error on the mobile
   I tried to use different browsers on my mobile device but the results are still the same, the form data will not submit

Comment: forgot to ** stringify** the data? as it is not actual formData.